# Changes to OrientDB graph are not reflecting to custom application - factory.getTx() obsolete?

Tags: spring, liferay, orientdb

I have two liferay portlets that work with OrientDB. First portlet constructs graph(GraphBuilder), second visualizes it(GraphVisualizer). I have also one application working with the OrientDB database(OrientDBPersistence) that both portlets use via spring beans. So it should work together in the following way. I create graph in GraphBuilder portlet and save it with custom label using OrientDBPersistence. Then I draw it using GraphVisualizer that asks OrientDBPersistence for graph with this particular label.

My problem is that once I create graph1 and save it, I am able to vizualize it, but when I create graph2 it cannot be retrieved by GraphVisualizer, because it is not present in DB. However when I look into the studio I can see it there. Like the graphs I make are not visible to the Visualizer until I restart the portal.

So in GraphDBPersistence I connect to OrientDB and I get the OrientGraph object to which I persist all my graphs with different label:

```
OrientGraph resultGraph = factory.getTx();
    resultGraph.setThreadMode(OrientBaseGraph.THREAD_MODE.ALWAYS_AUTOSET);
    return resultGraph;
```

Then I build a graph in GraphBuilder that has injeced beans from  OrientDBPersistence to perform saving with Label1. 
Saving looks like this:

```
 private void performGraphSaving(String label, OrientGraph graphO) {
    try{
        for(Vertex vertex : graph.getVertices()){
            constructVertex(vertex, graphO, label);
        }       

        for(SocialVertex vertex : graph.getVertices()){
            Collection<Edge> outEdges = graph.getOutEdges(vertex);
            for(Edge socOutEdge : outEdges){
                SocialVertex opposite = graph.getOpposite(vertex, socOutEdge);
                constructEdge(vertex, opposite, socOutEdge, graphO, label);
            }
        }
        graphO.commit();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.err.println(ex);
        graphO.rollback();
    }
}
```

I also call `graphO.shutdown();`. After graph is stored.

For example vertext retrieval looks like this:

```
public Set<Vertex> getAllNodesFromGraph(String graphLabel, OrientGraph graph) {
    Set<Vertex> labelledGraph = new HashSet<>();
    try{
        Iterable<Vertex> configGraph = graph.getVerticesOfClass(graphLabel);
        for(Vertex v : configGraph){
            labelledGraph.add(v);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        graph.rollback();
    }   
    return labelledGraph;
}
```

The retrieval always throws `(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class '133' was not found in database schema`, but I can see it in the studio.

No matter if I create this resultGraph once and I keep inside the bean, or I create it every time I access the bean, it always consist only the first graph I saved. After restarting portal, former graphs are visualized, but newly created are not found by the GraphDBPersistence.

Does anyone have any idea? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some kind of caching problem. Is it possible any portlet has its own cache? I think you should investigate the way you get the objects.
For example it is possible to have following scenario?

- portlet1 write A: it stores "graph A" in DB and create its cache;
- portlet2 read A: it accesses to DB, create its cache, get the existing "graph A"
- portlet1 write B: it stores "graph B" in DB and **update its** cache;
- portlet2 read B: it doesn't access to DB (because it "thinks" is the unique application accessing to database) and doesn't find the graph B (because it isn't in portlet2 cache)

What do you think about? Is it possible?

Comment: The first thing I was thinking about was, how I am working with this graph object, where I create it. So I tried following: everytime I access the OrientDB I create new Factory(url,login,pass) and get the graph from this factory. Therefore I think problem is somwhere in the way I create the connection, or get the graph.
So to me it seems like within the OrientDB pool the graph objects created from the factory are not the same.

Comment: Another attempt (I don't undestand if you already did it) is to avoid any intermediate layers (Spring for example). Only to "isolate" the problem, you can try to open the connections in a local (method scoped) variable of your portlet controller... if the error persiste yet you can exclude any other hipothesis